# Returning a 2D Array from a method using the class name as the input

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm receiving the error message "type mismatch cannot convert from String[][] to GameBoard[][]" on the line `return gameBoard;`.  How can I change this my public class GameBoard so that I am able to return string values in the 2D array?  (I do not want to change the methods return type to String[][])

````
public class GameBoard {

    String[][] gameBoard;


    /**
     * Constructor
     */

    public GameBoard() {
        gameBoard = new String[4][5];
    }   

    /**
     * Filling the playable board with Strings
     * @return
     */

     public GameBoard[][] fillGameBoard() {

        gameBoard[0][0] = new String("1");
        gameBoard[0][1] = new String("2");
        gameBoard[0][2] = new String("3");
        gameBoard[0][3] = new String("4");
        gameBoard[0][4] = new String("5");
        gameBoard[1][0] = new String("6");
        gameBoard[1][1] = new String("7");
        gameBoard[1][2] = new String("8");
        gameBoard[1][3] = new String("9");
        gameBoard[1][4] = new String("10");
        gameBoard[2][1] = new String("11");
        gameBoard[2][2] = new String("12");
        gameBoard[2][3] = new String("13");
        gameBoard[3][1] = new String("14");
        gameBoard[3][2] = new String("15");
        gameBoard[3][3] = new String("16");



        return gameBoard;

    }```
````

Comment: You do **not** need to use ```new String(...)```, using just the string literal is fine (this doesn't fix your problem, but is definitely important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you tell the compiler you are going to return a `GameBoard[][]` type but are actually returning a `String[][]` type, you probably confused yourself by naming your member variable the same way you named your class. You probably want to come up with a less confusing name for it.

Generally your approach of defining a class for your GameBoard is fine, since you probably want to perform different actions on it later on like, `move()` a content from 1 cell to another or something else. But remember, that your 'client-class' doesn't know about how the interior of your class looks and thus you cannot just store a `GameObject` as `String[][]` and vice versa

Here is an example of your class with some comments on how to declare variables that use your GameBoard along with suggestions:
(*This will not work as is, you have to remove the methods you do not want to use, since they are not matching in return types*)

```
public class GameBoard {

    String[][] gameBoard;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public GameBoard() {
        gameBoard = new String[4][5];
    }   

    // Approach 1
     public void fillGameBoard() {

        gameBoard[0][0] = "1";
        gameBoard[0][1] = "2";
        gameBoard[0][2] = "3";
        gameBoard[0][3] = "4";
        gameBoard[0][4] = "5";
        gameBoard[1][0] = "6";
        gameBoard[1][1] = "7";
        gameBoard[1][2] = "8";
        gameBoard[1][3] = "9";
        gameBoard[1][4] = "10";
        gameBoard[2][1] = "11";
        gameBoard[2][2] = "12";
        gameBoard[2][3] = "13";
        gameBoard[3][1] = "14";
        gameBoard[3][2] = "15";
        gameBoard[3][3] = "16";
    }

    // Approach 2
    // If you really want to go with the way you had your declaration set up
    // GameBoard board = new GameBoard().fillGameBoard();
    // you would have to do this
    public GameBoard fillGameBoard() {
        fillGameBoard();

        return this;
    }

    // Approach 3
    // If you want to do this, you don't need your class at all and your fillGameBoard 
    // has to return a String[][] type. I would recommend against it though,
    // since you are using a highly object oriented language as Java
    public String[][] fillGameBoard() {
        fillGameBoard();

        return gameBoard;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Approach 1
        // I recommend this approach!
        GameBoard board2 = new GameBoard();
        board2.fillGameBoard();

        // Approach 2
        GameBoard board = new GameBoard().fillGameBoard();

        // Approach 3
        String[][] board3 = new GameBoard().fillGameBoard();
    }
}
```

Comment: ```gameBoard``` is a ```String[][]```

Comment: It still returns the same error.  Should I change gameBoard away from String[][] type even though I want to return a 2D array of Strings?

Comment: That doesnt mean he can try to return a GameBoard[][] object. Anyhow, the function doesn't make a lot of sense. From what I see it shouldn't have a return value at all.

Comment: @DJSchaffner I need to return a 2D array with those numbers inside of it but they need to be strings.  Is there a better way to fill this board?

Comment: Yeah it should be String[][] not Gameboard return type, sorry i changed it. What i said still stands though

Comment: @oryan5000 filling in general like this is not that bad if you have a constant board size and don't mind the typing. But you probably want a seperate getBoard() method that will return your `gameBoard` value. I have to say though, naming it `gameBoard` is really confusing if you wrap it into a class called `GameBoard`.

Comment: But if I need to create another instance of GameBoard class and  fill it it won't work  ```GameBoard[][] gameBoard1 = new GameBoard().fillGameBoard();``` now I receive the same error when trying to create gameBoard1 due to the return type being set to String[][]

Comment: You have to decide what you want to store. A GameBoard object, or a String[][] object. You seem to be confusing what you want to do here and also missusing the class. I will update my answer in a sec to maybe make it more clear to you

Comment: You are confusing yourself because you are thinking of a GameBoard as being a 2-D array.  It is not.  It HAS a 2-D array, and that should be an implementation detail that is hidden from the caller.  Think of the class GameBoard as being more important and more knowledgeable than just its array of strings.  Imagine it also has an array of Moves, for instance, which kept track of the history of the game so far.  Once you think this way, it is clear that calling the internal array "gameBoard" was a bad idea.  Call it currentState, perhaps.

Comment: If you want to be able to create a new GameBoard from the current state of an existing one, that entire operation is private to GameBoards.  So create another GameBoard constructor that takes another gameBoard.  At that point, they can look inside the private contents of the other one because they are tied together in the code.  Imagine, though, that someday you want to change the internal storage to represent that 2D array some other way (perhaps a sparse array), all that code should live inside the GameBoard class and not leak out to the callers.

Comment: One other point.  Your constructor should always result in a GameBoard that is fully fleshed out and ready to use.  So you probably want to call fillGameBoard() from inside the constructor, because a GameBoard filled with arrays containing nulls is probably broken.  (Maybe not, if that is an OK state, ignore this comment.)

Comment: Sorry.  These were meant to be comments to the OP, not to this answer.

Comment: @oryan5000 i updated my answer, hope this helps you more.

Comment: @DJSchaffner thank you so much for updating.  The 2nd option worked perfectly for me.  Sorry, I'm new to Java (and object oriented programming in general) so my questions may be ignorant.  But is there a way for me to perform option 2 without putting it in the main method?

Comment: @Zag thank you for your well thought out replies.  You have given me a lot to think about and sent me in the right direction.  You advise putting methods in the constructor?  We have not been taught that in my Java course?

Comment: @oryan5000 i added the implementation of each option so yo ucan see what it looks like. Also, i swapped around option 1 and 2, just in case you are wondering :D I'm not sure if i understand your question correct. I just put it in there so i can have all of the answer in one file but obviously you can just import your class into any other class and create instances of GameBoard there aswell.

Comment: @oryan5000 It's a little bit of a loaded question with an answer that might be too subtle for you right now.  The bottom line is that your constructor should always result in a "legal" object, where you get to define that.  If every instance of the object would require Xxxx initialization before you could call anything other operations on it, then you should do Xxxx in the constructor.  ...

Comment: However, there is a problem calling overridden functions in the constructor.  e.g. say you had a class Shape, and you extend that class with classes Square and Circle.  It might be tempting to define a setup() method in Shape and then override it in the subclasses, so they do their own setup.  If you want to do this, then you can't call it in the constructor, the nascent object won't be ready, yet, for overridden functions to be called.  However, static functions and final functions are perfectly safe.